# What would be the best approch to display a commenting form in the ListView for each blog post?

Tags: python, django, forms, web

I currently have fully functional commenting form in my blog post view that I want to display in the ListView. Sort of like linkedin has under every list item, if you have noticed, i think facebook has the same thing.

Is there a shortcut to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you can combine a ListView with a FormMixin (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin)

In each item of list, you create your form html and checking if form exist and if form instance corresponds to current list view for displaying errors and data in case of invalid form sent.

```
class MyPostList(FormMixin, ListView);
    model = Post
    form = CommentAddForm
    template...


class CommentAddForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('post_id', 'txt'...)
```

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    {{post}}

    <form>
        {% if form.data.post_id == post.pk %}{{form.errors}}{% endif %}
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{post.pk}}" />
    </form>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, I am trying to display the same comment form that is currently in my post detail view in the list view but i am using a function based view, can I still use mix ins to accomplish this?

Comment: No. You can not use mixin with function based view. Mixins are only avalaible with Class based view. In Django function based view are reserved for small view. for big view like this, you have to use CBV. You can make your idea with a function, but you will rewrite all logic.